# After changed Date&Time, DatePicker showing old value (React, DatePicker)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datetime, time, datepicker

I have `DatePicker`:

```
    import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

    const { state } = useLocation();
    const [dateVisit, setDateVisit] = useState(new Date());
    
    const editVist = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log(dateVisit)
    }
    .....
    <form onSubmit={(e) => editVist(e}>
     <DatePicker
       selected={dateVisit}                                            
       onChange={date => setDateVisit(date)}
       value = {state.dataFiresStamp}                                            
       timeInputLabel="Time:"
       dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa"
       showTimeInput                                            
       withPortal
      />
   </form>
```

Values is correct set and display.

Now when I'm changing `Date&Time`. Then click `editVisit`. Into `console` is showing me corrected new date, but the `value into DatePicker has been not changed` (still is showing old value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did based on `https://reactdatepicker.com/`:

```
 const [dateVisit, setDateVisit] = useState();

 const editVist = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let updateDateVisit;
    
    if (dateVisit === undefined) {
            updateDateVisit = state.dataFiresStamp
        } else {
            updateDateVisit = dateVisit
        }
    } 
 ...
<DatePicker
 selected={dateVisit}
 onChange={date => setDateVisit(date)}
 placeholderText={state.dataFiresStamp}  //display data                                          
 timeInputLabel="Czas:"
 dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa"
 showTimeInput
 withPortal
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not put the `dateVisit` state in the `value` prop of DatePicker?

And you should be able to put `state.dataFiresStamp` as `defaultValue`

```
<DatePicker
   selected={dateVisit}                                            
   onChange={date => setDateVisit(date)}
   value = {dateVisit} // changed here
   defaultValue={state.dataFiresStamp} //added here                                            
   timeInputLabel="Time:"
   dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa"
   showTimeInput                                            
   withPortal
  />
```

Comment: now the DatePicker is showing wrong date coming from `state.dataFiresStamp` -  it`s showing actual dateTime (now)

Comment: You mean the defaultValue is not working? what if you give value={ dateVisit || state.dataFiresStamp} (so while dateVisit is null, undefined or false, you will see the state.dataFiresStamp date) and not dateTime (now)

Comment: when I did as @Shani said, my `DatePicker` when is loaded is `not taking date from state` - but is `display current Date&Time` (something like DateTime.Now()...but when I pick/change date from calendar - this is working ok

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const [dateVisit, setDateVisit] = useState(new Date());
const { state } = useLocation();

const setLocDate = () => {
   // exception occurs when the Date object contains an invalid date. new Date('undefined').toISOString();
   setDateVisit(state.dataFiresStamp);  
}

useEffect(() => {
  setLocDate();
});

 
<DatePicker
   ......
   value={dateVisit}  // change here                                           
   ......
 />
```

Comment: `React Hook "useLocation" is called in function "setLocDate" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

Comment: i got white screen and into console a lot of error:`Starting with v2.0.0-beta.1 date-fns doesn't accept strings as date arguments. Please use `parseISO` to parse strings. See: https://git.io/fjule `

Comment: `dataFiresStamp` = "24 december 2020, 14:30"

Comment: Use this way `import { parseISO, format } from 'date-fns';`
    
`parseISO('24 december 2020, 14:30')`

Comment: I put it do `setDateVisit(parseISO(state.dataFiresStamp));` but then got `Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value`

Comment: This exception occurs when the Date object contains an invalid date.

`new Date('undefined').toISOString()`

Comment: Updated my answer as it's an exception

Comment: useEffect did not help - into 'DatePicker` only `value = {state.dataFiresStamp}` is ok, but still when I change date DatePicker is not refreshed

Comment: `value` should come from the state so then it will reflect on the view

Comment: I have found this: `https://reactdatepicker.com/` and there props like `customTimeInput` but I don't really now how to setup there my date from state